# How to instruct KStream consumer not to commit the offset when a condition is not met

Tags: apache-kafka, stream, offset, apache-kafka-streams

We have a use-case where the Cache may not be populated occasionally. I need a way to instruct the Kstream consumer not to commit the offset when (cachePoplulated == false). The idea is to trigger a reload of the cache and try the reprocessing of the message from kafka. How can we achieve this.

Comment: For Kafka Streams this is not possible. However, with Kafka Streams is would also not easily be possible to reload the cache -- and if you solve the reprocessing problem via external tooling (like `bin/kafka-streams-application-reset.sh`) you also solve the commit problem as you can specify a desired start offset.

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax